# how to populate database table when we provide input fields by for loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('filters');
$select_no="";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> filters program</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
    Select No. OF Fields    <input type="number" style="width:100px;border-   radius:10px;" id="selct_no" name="select_no" value=""> To <input type="submit" name="create" id="create_fields" value="create" style="width:70px;border-radius:10px;" onclick="createFields()"> <br><br>

        <?php
        //IF CONDIOTIN FOR CREATIG ITEMS FIELD depend on user need....
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            $select_no=$_POST['select_no'];
        //FOR loop for creating fileds...  
      // loop for generating given no. of fields... 
            for ($i=0; $i < $select_no ; $i++) { 
                global $x;
                $x = $i+1;

                echo $x.'.) Enter Products Name and Prices.... <br>' ;
                echo "<input type='text' style='width:300px; height:25px; border-radius:10px;' placeholder='Enter Items' id='id_item' name='items".$x."' value=''> <input type='text' style='width:100px;height:25px; border-radius:10px;' placeholder='Price' id='id_price' name='price".$x."' value=''> <br/><br/> ";
        }       
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button name='submit'                     
                    style='width:300px;height:25px;border-radius:10px'     id='submit_cat'>submit</button>";
        echo "<br><No of created fields are ".$x;

}
        //if condition for saving data in database table name filters and table name products....
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            global $x;
            for ($a=1;$a<=$x;$a++){
                $product=$_POST["items".$a];
                $price=$_POST["price".$a];
                echo "$product";
                echo "$price";
                $sql= "INSERT INTO products SET     product='$product',price='$price'";
                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                if ($res) {
                echo " data submitted Successfully";
                }else{
                echo "Not submitted because ".mysql_error();}
        }
    }


?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here what i want is that, some buddy please tell me by what concept i'll make populated that information each and every details in my database table

here i provide snapeshot also for your understanding.....[this is the first view when we enter value it will creat fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI9gk.png)
[in this image 4 fields are created when we press (create) button after enter 4 in first input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYblx.png)

Comment: invalid insert query. Please look into the syntax of insert query in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in insert query, form your query like this

```
  INSERT INTO table_name  
 (column1,column2,column3,...)
  VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

EDIT:
Problem was with GLOBAL variable, missing form and input query, here is working solution:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> filters program</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            //if condition for saving data in database table name filters and table name products....
            if(isset($_POST['name_s'])){
                session_start();
                $x = $_SESSION["number_of_x"];
                for ($a=1;$a<=$x;$a++){
                    $product=$_POST["items".$a];
                    $price=$_POST["price".$a];
                    echo "$product";
                    echo "$price";
                    $sql= "INSERT INTO products (product, price) VALUES('$product','$price')";
                    $res=mysql_query($sql);
                    if ($res) {
                    echo " data submitted Successfully";
                    }else{
                    echo "Not submitted because ".mysql_error();}
                }
            }else{
            ?>
                <form method="POST" action="#">
                    Select No. OF Fields    <input type="number" style="width:100px;border-   radius:10px;" id="selct_no" name="select_no" value=""> To <input type="submit" name="create" id="create_fields" value="create" style="width:70px;border-radius:10px;" onclick="createFields()"> <br><br>
                </form>
            <?php
            }
            //IF CONDIOTIN FOR CREATIG ITEMS FIELD depend on user need....
            if(isset($_POST['create'])){
                $select_no=$_POST['select_no'];
                // Start the session
                session_start();
                 $_SESSION["number_of_x"] = $_POST['select_no'];
            //FOR loop for creating fileds...  
            // loop for generating given no. of fields... 
            ?>
            <form method="POST" action="#">
            <?php
                for ($i=0; $i < $select_no ; $i++) { 
                    global $x;
                    $x = $i+1;

                    echo $x.'.) Enter Products Name and Prices.... <br>' ;
                    echo "<input type='text' style='width:300px; height:25px; border-radius:10px;' placeholder='Enter Items' id='id_item' name='items".$x."' value=''> <input type='text' style='width:100px;height:25px; border-radius:10px;' placeholder='Price' id='id_price' name='price".$x."' value=''> <br/><br/> ";
                }       
            ?>
               <input type="submit" name='name_s'  style='width:300px;height:25px;border-radius:10px'     id='submit_cat'></input>";
            </form>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actully sir its my mistake that i did not see my code before posting it
there is in my code between two comments i missed this two line as shown below 


`//  IF CONDIOTIN FOR CREATIG ITEMS FIELD....

if(isset($_POST['create'])){

$select_no=$_POST['select_no'];

//FOR loop for creating fileds...`



and problem is that it my cod will not enter in 


`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ }`


soo please help me for that 
thanks in advance.....

Comment: The thing is your submit button is not doing anything as i can see, you need to create <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"> and inside this form put your submit button and inputs

Comment: Try this edited solution, hope that will help you :)

Comment: Hey thank you soo much for your valuable time i am glad to have my account on stackoverflow....

thanku soo much ....

Comment: I am glad I could help :)